# Groupby with brackets vs. Groupby with ".agg"?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

what is the exact difference between

```
data_sex1= data_suicide.groupby(by=["year", "sex"])["suicides_no"].sum()
```

and

```
data_sex2 = data_suicide.groupby(by=['year', 'sex']).agg({'suicides_no': ['sum']})
```

?

My problem is that I have to modify both to plot them in seaborn.
The line for seaborn is this

```
sns.barplot(x="year", y="suicides_no", hue="sex", data=data_sex1)
sns.barplot(x="year", y="suicides_no", hue="sex", data=data_sex2)
```

Now for the upper example `data_sex1` I have to add following line to make the plot work. Because that is the way to not only reset the indexes, but also add the name `"suicides_no"` to the column. The column had no name before.

```
data_sex1=data_sex1.reset_index()
```

Now for the second example `data_sex2` I have to add following code to make the plot work. And please also note, that if I reset the index first and then rename the column, it also give me an error.

```
data_sex2.columns=["suicide_no"]    
data_sex2=data_sex2.reset_index()
```

So I hope someone can really help me with this super confusing problem. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You would like to use agg when you want to apply different aggregation functions for different columns:

```
df.groupby('id').agg({'x': ['mean', 'sum', 'max'], 'y': ['sum', 'min']})
```

The other option gives you less flexibility in terms of columns / aggregation logics to apply.

Comment: Thanks so much. I was also confused, why the ".agg" option gives me a Multi-Index. I think that is the reason why I have to rename the column.